# Comparing CLOB, BLOB values in Oracle, Postgres and SQLite

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlite, blob, clob

This involves comparing tables in two different DB schema. The requirement is to traverse a known set of tables and ensure that the table data in both the schema are identical. At the moment we are doing a similar operation on Oracle with a query like the following:

For each table;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA1.MY_TABLE MINUS (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA2.MY_TABLE));
```

But above query has a limitation in oracle when it comes to large objects:

```
ERROR at line 1: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB
```

Apparently, the limitation exists for all set operations in Oracle when it comes to large objects as [detailed here](https://technology.amis.nl/2012/07/04/compare-tables-with-the-minus-operator-even-if-they-contain-clobs-andor-blobs/). It could be overcome by using DB specific functions like `dbms_lob.compare`.

As I have limited exposure to Postgres and SQLite I would like to know;

- Are there similar limitations in using set operators like union, minus, or intersect in Postgres and SQLite when it comes to LOB values?
- If there are limitations, are there any DB specific functions which should be used for LOB comparison?

Comment: The equivalent data type in Postgres would be `text` or an unlimited `varchar` and it would work without problems there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL/SQLite, the `text`/`TEXT` and `bytea`/`BLOB` data types behave just like smaller values and can be compared normally.